# Installing Joomla extensions on Ubuntu localhost

Tags: ubuntu, joomla

My Joomla 2.5.4 installation folder is /var/www/Joomla_2.5.4/

When I try to install new extensions, templates, etc errors arise because /var/www/ requires root access to move or create directories or files. How do I grant Joomla root access or is there any other workaround to this problem?

Cheers and thanks

Comment: same problem for me. i had to test an extension for mobile device access. it was on a virtual machine so i didn't care about security. a "sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/joomla" did the work.

Comment: chown (or chmod 777) the folder to the user that the web server runs on.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a virtual host for your project? To create a virtual host:

1. go to terminal => `$ sudo etc/hosts/`
                 => `127.0.0.1      joomla`
2. create and write to that host:
                 =>

   $ sudo touch /etc/apache2/sites-available/joomla
                        $ sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/joomla
                 Then write the following in that file:

   ```
         <VirtualHost *:80>
               DocumentRoot /home/usr/path/your_joomla_project/
               ServerName joomla
               <Directory />
                  Options FollowSymLinks
                  AllowOverride All
                  Order allow,deny
                  allow from all
               </Directory>
         </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Enable that host => `$ sudo a2ensite joomla`
4. Restarting apache2 => `$ sudo service apache2 restart`

Here I think the `'your_joomla_project'` folder is not writable yet, then

```
                  => `$ sudo chmod 777 -R /home/usr/path/your_joomla_project/`
```

- To access your site, just type `joomla` in the browser address bar.

Then I'm sure it does not ask you again for any permission.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure I follow. Do I need to reinstall Joomla again?

Comment: I don’t understand =/ Is that a virtual Apache?

Comment: yeah, for those who use Linux. I use Ubuntu 12.04 version

Answer (score 0):

agree with Jason above.  I know this is an old thread but in my environment 777 is dangerous as any user can read/write/mod those files, so simply change ownership of your joomla directory to apache (this is for Ubuntu not sure the apache user/group for other distros)

```
chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/Your_Joomla_File
```